# Why is JDK assumed to be pre-installed but not Scala in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

To my understanding, SBT projects use the JDK installed on your machine (albeit compiling for potentially older versions of the framework). In other words, the JDK is inherited as an 'ambient dependency' of the project; it is assumed to be installed on the developer's machine.

However, the specific versions of Scala lib/compiler/etc are treated as normal dependencies. IE they are downloaded for your project (although ultimately cached by SBT for use in other projects, should they require the same version).

My question is: Why don't SBT projects use the environment's install of Scala, like they do for JDK, rather than downloading their own copy?

Comment: SBT cannot be run without java runtime (it is jvm based tool), but is tolerant to lack of scala, since at the end of the day every scala application can be treated as java application with additional dependency jar.

Comment: some more info: scala's versions are incompatible and generates incompatible libraries, so one project may have number of scala version inside, but it may work with any realization of java virtual machine both in terms of versions and manufacturer

Comment: @ayvango just to clarify, **major** scala versions are *binary* incompatible, e.g. 2.9.* are incompatible with 2.10.* branch. But, with modern scala versions nothing stops you from swapping 2.9.1 with say, 2.9.2 version. Moreover, it is likely that scala support two version window for source compatibility (so even if you had 2.9.x version of some library, you could just recompile that library to run against 2.10.x code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications running on the JVM cannot just have the java library as a regular dependency.

In other words, you don't just add a `java-1.7.jar` dependency by example. That is because a given version of the Java library jar will only work with a given implementation of the JVM. Having the java library itself as a dependency would essentially make your application runnable only with a given JVM implementation (which may also imply "on a given OS"), totally defeating the purpose of [Java's "Write once, run anywhere"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere).

The Scala library, on the other hand, depends on the standard Java library itself only, which is already provided by the host JVM. Thus it can be added as a standard dependency. And if it can, why on earth would you want to trade this simple situation for a situation where the end user would need to install Scala on his machine before being able to run any Scala program?

That might be fine (and maybe even desirable at times) in some cases, but it is easy to see how much more problematic deployment scenarios would be.